# Pronunciation of the word " stingy"

Tags: pronunciation

I heard the word "stingy" which was pronounced with the "g" like in the word "ground" in context of some soreness in mouth or so (caused by some chemicals) - is it the different word from "stingy" person? Stingy person we say "steenjee", not stingy with G of "ground".

Thanks.

UPD 
Can someone answer the question? I see a lot of comments but no one wants to answer. 
Let me ask it in a simpler way -  does this word "stingy" with hard g exists? I did not find any such transcription in any dictionary.

Comment: Not always. Some people pronounce "g" of singer, but people generally don't. The adjective *stingy* derived from the verb *sting* is same. Some pronounce "g", but people generally don't.

Comment: @Rathony: I have *never* heard anyone pronounce ***stingy*** with anything other than a soft **g** (apart from maybe a child using it inappropriately with the archaic sense *having sting-like attributes*). Interestingly, [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stingy) says the current meaning *(niggardly, penurious, extremely tight-fisted)* was first recorded in the 1650s, but it's *of **uncertain origin**, perhaps a dialectal alteration of earlier stingy "biting, sharp, stinging" (1610s), from sting (v.).* So it's at least *possible* they're etymologically unrelated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It might be a difference between AmE and BrE, but the IPA pronunciation of stingy is [/ˈstɪŋi/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stingy). I don't think the two adjectives have the same root, either.

Comment: With a **soft g** it means someone who does not spend money, with a **hard g** it means something that has a sting-like quality, ie the **stingy thingy** (sting-ee thing-ee) where a long **ee** is added (to pretty much anything) to "make" it an adjective.

Comment: If we're ignoring the main *current* meaning of ***stingy***, the issue is just whether **ng** is "nasalised" or not (it is, for almost all speakers). In which case better examples might be, say, ***stringy*** or ***slangy*** (or ***hanger, singer***, etc., come to that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. The OP is asking about the adjective (from the verb *sting*) that is not the *main* *current* meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: if *hinge* and *hang* can come from the same root, I don't see why *stingy* and *sting* couldn't.

Comment: @Peter: Nor I. But I did find it "interesting" that etymonline refuses to commit itself. In fact, I've just checked the full OED, which says that's only a ***possible*** origin. They mark all three usages that obviously relate to the "having a sting" sense as either obsolete or dialectal (within which category I'd include my earlier reference to "a child using it inappropriately").

Comment: "steen-jee" is incorrect for "stingy", for a different reason. The first sound of "stingy" is a near-close near-front unrounded vowel /ɪ/ (the English short I). The -y suffix is /i:/, something like a lengthened close front unrounded vowel. They are very different. More correct is "stin-jee".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When describing something that stings, it is more common to use *stinging*. Using *stingy* in this way is, I would say, a legitimate use of language, but it sounds highly unusual and somewhat childish to my ear. Using in this way I would **always** use a hard *G* sound to distinguish it from the much more common homonym. I don't think anyone would understand what you meant if you said you had a "stinjy" feeling in your mouth.

Comment: Oh, great answer! +1